# Sort with moment.js: Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, momentjs

I parse dates I get from an API with Moment, and I need to sort the array when I'm done collecting the data. I currently have this:

```
myobject.name = name;
myobject.time = Moment(ajaxinfo.startdate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
array.push(myobject);
// ... more data is added ...
array.sort((left, right) => {
    return Moment.utc(left.time).diff(Moment.utc(right.time));
});
```

`ajaxinfo.startdate` is a string that I get from an API, and it looks like `"2018-01-28T13:00:00+00:00"`

But the above code doesn't work. It gives me a warning:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. `moment` construction falls back to js `Date()`, which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Stop formatting your parsed date as a string, especially not as a non standard confirming string.

Comment: I do get the date from an API which gives the date as a string, such as "2018-01-28T13:00:00+00:00". How should I parse this instead?

Comment: Please provide sample data. As it is currently written there is no visible connection between the `time` variable and `array`. Can you provide a script that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I added more content to the post, @trincot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the link to the momentjs docs in the warning, browsers may be unreliable or inconsistent in parsing the format you're providing `"DD/MM/YYYY"`. If you need to keep this format, one solution would be to provide the format when converting the string back to a moment object when calculating the `diff`. So you could do
`return moment.utc(left.timeStamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY').diff(moment.utc(right.timeStamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))`

Answer (score 8):

As stated by others the format "DD/MM/YYYY" is not an ISO 8601 format and the resulting strings can be ambiguous.

You should really work with Date or moment objects, not strings.

So don't call `format` when you store the dates in your array objects. If ever you need to render the date, call `format` at that very time.

```js
const Moment = moment;

// Sample strings
var ajaxinfos = [
    { name: "x", startdate: "2018-01-28T13:00:00+00:00" },
    { name: "y", startdate: "2018-01-26T18:00:00+00:00" }
];

const array = [];
for (const ajaxinfo of ajaxinfos) {
    const myobject = {};
    myobject.name = ajaxinfo.name;
    myobject.time = Moment(ajaxinfo.startdate);  // don't call format
    array.push(myobject);
}

// No more need to convert strings to dates while sorting:
array.sort((left, right) => left.time.diff(right.time));
console.log(array);

// Whenever you need to format:
const formatted = array.map(info => info.time.format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
console.log(formatted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```