# Sort JavaScript nested object by ISOString date

Tags: javascript, date, object

I have this object and I want to return a new object sorted by ascending date, taking into account the startTime that is a ISOString. (I'm also using moment) How can I do this?

```
const clinics = {
  "a0CW00000027OX3MAM": {
    "id": "a0CW00000027OX3MAM",
    "companyName": "Hendrick Medical Center",
    "startTime": "2018-08-10T05:30:00.000Z",
  },
  "a0CW00000026gjJMAQ": {
    "id": "a0CW00000026gjJMAQ",
    "companyName": "ABC Manufacturing",
    "startTime": "2018-08-10T10:36:00.000Z",
  },
  "a0CW00000026gipMAA": {
    "id": "a0CW00000026gipMAA",
    "companyName": "ABC Manufacturing",
    "startTime": "2018-08-01T10:36:00.000Z",
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692757/sort-with-moment-js)

Comment: ISO strings have the benefit of ordering correctly when sorted as a string. Have you tried just sorting by the string value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Sort array by ISO 8601 date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192491/jquery-sort-array-by-iso-8601-date)

Comment: "*…a new object sorted by ascending date…*". You can't order the properties of an Object, they are unordered by specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will sort the clinics by start time in ascending order.

- It works by first converting the object property values into an array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).
- The values are sorted into ascending order using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
- Finally a new object is created using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const clinics = {
  "a0CW00000027OX3MAM": {
    "id": "a0CW00000027OX3MAM",
    "companyName": "Hendrick Medical Center",
    "startTime": "2018-08-10T05:30:00.000Z",
  },
  "a0CW00000026gjJMAQ": {
    "id": "a0CW00000026gjJMAQ",
    "companyName": "ABC Manufacturing",
    "startTime": "2018-08-10T10:36:00.000Z",
  },
  "a0CW00000026gipMAA": {
    "id": "a0CW00000026gipMAA",
    "companyName": "ABC Manufacturing",
    "startTime": "2018-08-01T10:36:00.000Z",
  }
};

const sorted = Object.values(clinics)
  .sort((a, b) => a.startTime > b.startTime)
  .reduce((m, c) => m.set(c.id, c), new Map());

for (let [key, value] of sorted.entries()) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

**Edit** - answer updated to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), to guarantee property ordering.

Comment: You can't guarantee the order of object properties, they are unordered.

Comment: @RobG, cheers. I thought I'd read somewhere that `Object` property ordering was guaranteed in ES6+, but I seem to have been mistaken. I've updated my answer to use a `Map` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well your object isn't an array so you cant really sort it without converting it to an array first. Here is an example of converting it to an array and then sorting just using the text of the field because ISO will sort fine that way.

**EDIT** I updated it to add a function to convert it back to an object

```js
const clinics = {
  "a0CW00000027OX3MAM": {
    "id": "a0CW00000027OX3MAM",
    "companyName": "Hendrick Medical Center",
    "startTime": "2018-08-10T05:30:00.000Z",
  },
  "a0CW00000026gjJMAQ": {
    "id": "a0CW00000026gjJMAQ",
    "companyName": "ABC Manufacturing",
    "startTime": "2018-08-10T10:36:00.000Z",
  },
  "a0CW00000026gipMAA": {
    "id": "a0CW00000026gipMAA",
    "companyName": "ABC Manufacturing",
    "startTime": "2018-08-01T10:36:00.000Z",
  }
}

function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.startTime < b.startTime)
     return -1;
  if (a.startTime > b.startTime)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

function objectToArray(obj){
 var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var ret = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
   ret.push(obj[keys[i]]);
    
  return ret;
}

function arrayToObject(arr){
 var ret = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    ret[arr[i].id] = arr[i];
  return ret;
}

var arr = objectToArray(clinics);
console.log(arr.sort(compare));
console.log(arrayToObject(arr));
```