# Descending order date using moment.js in jquery?

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I have array of dates from my json response.I am using moment.js to format my date its working fine.But,Now what i want is using same moment.js to order date in desc order.
This is my line of code to format date using moment:

```
tableContent += "<li>"+moment(response[itr][segment]).format('MM-DD-YYYY')+"</li>";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692757/sort-with-moment-js)

Comment: No,this not the possible duplicate.This answer not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach, which is not bound to momentjs:

```js
Array.orderBy = (array, method, desc) => {
  var pre = desc ? -1 : 1
  var cmp = (a,b,p) => pre*(a[p]() < b[p]() ? -1 : (a[p]() > b[p]() ? 1 : 0));
  return array.sort((a,b) => cmp(a,b,method) )
};

var dates = ["2019-02-18","2019-02-16","2019-02-17","2019-02-19","2019-02-22","2019-02-21","2019-02-20"].map(x => moment(x))
console.log(dates)

console.log(Array.orderBy(dates, 'valueOf', true)) // descending
console.log(Array.orderBy(dates, 'valueOf'))       // ascending
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

However, you will need to save all `response[itr][segment]` values in an intermediate array first. Then sort it, then build the list.

Comment: I am using like this  var dateArray = [];
      dateArray.push(moment(response[itr][segment]).format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
      // console.log(dateArray);
      console.log(Array.orderBy(dateArray, 'valueOf', true)) but still i am not getting desc order.

Comment: Because you are calling format. Don't call before ordering. My solution is using moment instances, not strings.

Comment: Yes ur right I am not calling.Mentioned above is wrong.var dateArray = [];
      dateArray.push(response[itr][segment]);
      // console.log(dateArray);
      console.log(Array.orderBy(dateArray, 'valueOf', true)) like this only i called But still not getting output["2019-02-16"]
["2019-02-17"]
 ["2019-02-18"]
 ["2019-02-19"]
 ["2019-02-20"]
 ["2019-02-21"]
 ["2019-02-22"] i am getting this output only. But actually i want inthis order below:["2019-02-22"], ["2019-02-21"]...etc

Comment: I have changed the sample above. I have used your dates. And it is ordered descending as you want. Have you run the snippet? You are doing something different as you say you do.

Comment: Its working in your snippet.But when i am using the same in my code like this var dateArray = [];
      dateArray.push(response[itr][segment]);
      console.log(Array.orderBy(dateArray, 'valueOf', true)); it wont work.I am getting the desc order format

Comment: My response[itr][segment] output is :                                                               2019-02-16
2019-02-17
 2019-02-18
 2019-02-19
 2019-02-20
 2019-02-21
 2019-02-22

Comment: So your input is ascending? Than why don't you simply reverse order?

Comment: Anyway, please answer these questions: 1) do you want **ascending** or **descending** order as result? 2) in your code after calling my method, do you get **ascending**, **descending** or **unordered** result?

Comment: I want descending order as result.After calling your method i am getting ascending only

Comment: Sorry, but it looks to be impossible to understand what's going on differently in your code without seeing the rest or at least a relevant part of your code.

Comment: I am calling your method at top of my js file:                                                                                 Array.orderBy = (array, method, desc) => {
  var pre = desc ? -1 : 1
  var cmp = (a,b,p) => pre*(a[p]() < b[p]() ? -1 : (a[p]() > b[p]() ? 1 : 0));
  return array.sort((a,b) => cmp(a,b,method) )
};    and calling like this:            console.log(Array.orderBy(dateArray, 'valueOf', true));

Comment: My dateArray:var dateArray = [];
      dateArray.push(response[itr][segment]);

Comment: As this way you are pushing only a single value, you are certainly not doing this - 
 if yes, you are doing something bad wrong. I suggest you create a reproducible snippet on jsfiddle or any of its alternatives (https://www.slant.co/options/2229/alternatives/~jsfiddle-alternatives)

Comment: response[itr][segment] i getting this after iterating for loop only.

Comment: I am not pushing only single value i am pushing all

Comment: As I said: I can't help you further without seeing a code snippet that resembles your code and is not working as expected. Please create a snippet on any of the playgrounds and share. Or better use the snippet function of stackoverflow. I can't see your screen, and I can't read your mind either...