# MomentJS - convert YYYYMMDD and HH:MM to YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss

Tags: momentjs

I get two separate time and date values from my API.

```
date: 20190404
time: 09:30
```

I want to combine the two in one acceptable format, such as YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.

I have tried the following:

```
moment(data[i].date + 'T' + data[i].time).valueOf()
```

but I get the following error in the console:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
```

and the value in my array shows as 'NaN'

Thanks!

Comment: Specify the format manually, per https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ See the difference between `moment(..)` and `moment.utc(..)` noted that the top of https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48692757/2864740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Concatenate the date and time without space and add the format as the second parameter of moment()

```js
var moment = require("moment")
var data = {date: '20190404',
time: '09:30'}
var joined = `${data.date}${data.time}`
console.log(moment(joined, 'YYYYMMDDh:mm:ss').format()) 
// "2019-04-04T09:30:00+01:00"
```

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar in the end, but this is more elegant.